# How to upload an image (given in form of data-URL from HTML canvas) to facebook?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, api, canvas

In my web page, I have an HTML canvas. I want to upload the canvas image to facebook. I think the first step may be a canvasContext.toDataURL() function call. What's next? If the user is logged in to facebook, I want him/her to be able to upload the image automatically with his facebook account from my page. I want the user will be able to either post the image in his/her wall or one of his/her friends. What should be the code? And where should I add the code? A detail answer (in javascript or jQuery) will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I know it's really hard to acces facebook externally, one of the reasons is because they change their acces scripts often. I don't have a clear answer to your question, but maybe you can find it at the developers website of facebook: [Facebook Developers](http://developers.facebook.com/).
This site contains all the code and a lot of examples you can use to acces facebook (such as the like buttons you find all over the internet). I hope you can find your answer there.
greets!

Answer (score 1):

check [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#plugins)

First you'll need to use the Authentication plugin to give your website access to their Facebook.

Then use the [Graph API - Post](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) to post to their wall...